# Is it possible to split Vim window to view multiple files at once?

Tags: split

When working with multiple files, it would be very handy if we can see more than one file in the screen at once. Is there any way in Vim to split the window (horizontally or vertically) so each split can show a different file?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Yes, vim has the ability to split both horizontally using `:split` and vertically using `:vsplit` which both work just like `:edit` for opening a file, except they open it in a horizontal / vertical split respectively.

Additionally, I would recommend to also read `:h window-move-cursor` for moving around different splits with ease.

Answer (score 36):

Yes, there are the `:split` (split into two windows, top half and bottom half) and `:vsplit` (left and right) commands. You can then use <kbd>Ctrl-W *direction*</kbd> to switch windows (where *direction* is one of the normal hjkl cursor movement keys, or the arrow keys).

You can then `:edit` (etc.) a different file in each window.

Full documentation is at `:help windows.txt`.

Answer (score 27):

You can either split vim windows by [opening multiple files](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/732/467) using `-o`, `-O`, `-o2` parameters.

Or if you're already editing multiple files in one window, you can use `:ba` to [split horizontally](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/758/467) or `:vert ba` to split vertically.

> :[N]ba[ll] [N]
>   :[N]sba[ll] [N] Rearrange the screen to open one window for each buffer in the buffer list.
>
> :vert[ical] {cmd} Execute {cmd}.  If it contains a command that splits a window, it will be split vertically.

[To quit](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/735/467), use: `:qa`.

---

See also:

- [How to open multiple files in split mode?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/732/467)
- [How to convert all windows into horizontal, vertical or tab splits?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/758/467)

Answer (score 15):

You can use `:split` or `:vsplit` for horizontal and vertical splits respectively. Provide the path to the file you want to open to open a specific file. Or just type the command to open a copy if the current file.

You can then move between splits using `C-w + hjkl`.

Comment: A shortcut for a horizontal split is `:sp`, with the vertical shortcut being `:vsp`.