# How to exit Vim from split mode?

Tags: split, quit

How to efficiently exit Vim when editing multiple files in the split mode at one go?

It seems when I'm having e.g. 10 split windows, I've to repeat 10 times `:q!` command for each window which is a bit time consuming.

Are there any better methods of quitting the editor?

As for dirty workaround, it can be quit by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and typing `kill %1` to kill it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the command `:qall!`, `:qa!` for short, or its safer alternative `:qall` that prevent to discard modified buffers. To save all buffers before quitting use the command `:wqall`. See `:help window-exit` for the full set of commands to quit multiple windows at once.

Answer (score 0):

These commands also works:

- `:windo :q` - executes `:q` in each window
- `:bufdo :q` - executes `:q` in each buffer

Related:

- [How do I close all open tabs at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510325/how-do-i-close-all-open-tabs-in-vim-at-once) at stackoverflow

Comment: Are there effective differences between using this or `:qa`?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker No difference other that someone can learn something new. One of advantages is that it allows to execute additional custom commands for each window before closing them, but I can't think of practical example yet.

Comment: Okay :-) Just curious if this would somehow behave subtly different or something...