# Modification of a tab's windows to specified format

Tags: tabbed-user-interface

I have the following structure of a tab in Vim. `x` marks the cursor position. (Note that I don't have control over how these windows are placed in the tab in the first place. It is the default debug output in [Vimspector](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector) for those interested. There seems to be no easy way to customize the user interface of Vimspector.)

```
________________________________
a  |  d               |e        |
___|                  |         |
b  |                  |         |
___|    x             |         |  
c  |__________________|_________|
___|____________f_______________|
```

I would eventually like to obtain

```
________________________________
b  |  d                         |
___|    x                       |
c  |                            |
___|____________________________|
                                |
________________e_______________|
```

To do this, I started with `:windo wincmd K<CR>` based on suggestion [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/758/how-to-convert-all-windows-into-horizontal-vertical-or-tab-splits).

That gave rise to all windows being horizontally placed thus:

```
________________________________
______________f_____x___________|
______________e_________________|
______________d_________________|
______________c_________________|
______________b_________________|
______________a_________________|
```

Then, `<C-W>c` closed window `f`. But beyond this, I am stumped. I have looked at `<C-W>H`and `<C-W>K`, but am unable to figure out the exact steps and sequence in which the output tab can be obtained in the format specified above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just close A and F and then from E do `ctrl+w J`?

Comment: @BLayer Indeed. I think that would work.

Comment: Groovy. :) Welcome to Vi & Vim SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, I'm sure, but it seems to me that a very straightforward approach is to...

1. Close windows A and F (for example, just move the cursor to each one and do `:close`).

That'll leave you with:

```
_____________________________
 B  |  D         | E          |
    |            |            |
____|            |            |
 C  |            |            |
__ _|____________|____________|
```

2. Move to E and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

That command moves the current window to the very bottom of the screen while taking up the entire width, i.e. your desired end state.

See [`:h CTRL-W_J`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#CTRL-W_J)