# Close all split files, except the one currently focused?

Tags: command-line, split, vim-windows

Sometimes when I'm working on a file, I'll open up multiple files just to get an idea of the current flow of the code up to a point. However this sometimes leads to multiple files being open at a time by split. Is there a command to quit all except the selected window?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert all windows into horizontal, vertical or tab splits?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/758/how-to-convert-all-windows-into-horizontal-vertical-or-tab-splits)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you want to close all windows(splits) except the current one:

```
:only
```

If you want to close all tabs except the current one:

```
:tabonly
```

If you want to delete all hidden buffers (files open but not visible in any window on any tab), you'll have to add a function to your vimrc. Some people have posted possible functions to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534835/how-do-i-close-all-buffers-that-arent-shown-in-a-window-in-vim) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450919/how-can-i-delete-all-hidden-buffers)

I'm not sure exactly which of these you were trying to accomplish, but hopefully some combination of these commands does the trick.

Answer (score 53):

Press <kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd>,<kbd>o</kbd> to quickly close all split windows, but current one.

Alternatively use the command: `:on` (`:only`).

> :on[ly][!]      Make the current window the only one on the screen. All other windows are closed.

See also:

- [How to convert all windows into horizontal, vertical or tab splits?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/758/467) at Vim SE
- [How to cancel splitted windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809729/cancel-split-window-in-vim) at stackoverflow SE
- [Is it possible to split Vim window to view multiple files at once?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/64/467)

Comment: Ctrl+W,o <<< this should be accepted answer

Comment: It'd be cool if you could toggle splits, like zoom in Tmux. Anyone know if that's possible?

Comment: @portOdin You need to ask another question then.

Comment: Does "close" here mean closing the buffers (equivalent of `:q`) or just hiding them?

Comment: @stillanoob I think they're closed, as `:tabs` doesn't show them.