# How to open multiple file with single split command?

Tags: vim-windows

I can open and split multiple file like this

```
:split file1
:split file2
:split file3
```

But is there any way to open multiple files in a single command? Something like this

```
:split file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/840/22375)? `ba` seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Biggybi `ba` opens all my buffer. But I don't want that. I want to open files may be not in the buffer or not all the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible with the default `:split` command; you'll have to use a custom command such as `:Split` (capital S) which loops over all the commandline arguments and calls `:split`:

```
:command! -nargs=+ -complete=file Split
            \  for s:f in [<f-args>]
            \|   exe 'split' fnameescape(s:f)
            \| endfor
            \| unlet s:f
```

You can improve that a bit more by calling `glob()`, so that `:Split *.vim` will work as well:

```
:command! -nargs=+ -complete=file Split
            \  for s:f in [<f-args>]
            \|   for s:m in glob(s:f, 0, 1)
            \|     exe 'split' fnameescape(s:m)
            \|   endfor
            \| endfor
            \| unlet s:f | unlet s:m
```

I wrote [a little plugin](https://github.com/arp242/globedit.vim) a few years ago which does that for `:Tabedit`, `:Edit`, `:Split`, and `:Vsplit`.

---

Related: [How can I open multiple tabs at once?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2108/51)

Comment: I tried `:argdo split` before you posted your answer, but the problem I had with that one is that you end up with the last file in the args list opened twice. (Not horrible, easy to drop one of the splits, but still it's not a perfect solution as is.)

Comment: Oh right @filbranden; I now remember that's actually one of the reasons I never use this. I'll just remove that part; someone else can provide an answer based on that with more details.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on Martin's [solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/24900/5017)

It add [:h <mods>](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Cmods%3E) to let you choose the split style, and [:h :command-bang](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-bang) to let you decide whether existing windows or tabs should be closed.

It's implemented by `lambda`, this `lambda` is composed of two `execute(...)` connected by `.`(All expressions within one level are parsed from left to right).

```
com -nargs=+ -bang -complete=file Split
      \ call map( [<f-args>], { i,v -> execute('<mods> split ' . fnameescape(v) )
      \ . ( i == 0 && <bang>0 &&
      \    execute('<mods>' =~# 'tab' ? 'tabonly' : 'wincmd o') ) } )
```

examples:

```
# split 3 new windows
Split a b c

# close existing windows, split 3 new right below windows
rightbelow Split! a b c

# close existing tabs, split 3 new tabs
tab Split! a b c
```

I didn't add the `glob` part, you can use [:h c_CTRL-A](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-A) to expand the pattern into command line directly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the argument list for this.

First, populate it with the file you need with `:args` ([:h :args](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:args)).
Then, use it to open its entries in a split with `:all` ([:h all](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:all)) (or `:vert all` for vertical splits).

```
:args file* | all
```

(`file*` will grab any file name starting with `file`.)